# Secure a Cocoa Touch Library with Remote Server, Local Script, and License-Key

Tags: ios, security, deployment, licensing, static-libraries

**Background**

I want to create a Cocoa Touch library where others will be limited to a finite number deployment builds using said library. However, there should be no limitations on the number of development builds.

I was considering a remote server which generates license-keys each associated with the library and a number of permitted deployment builds on the library.

When the user of the library builds for deployment, I need to check against the keys on the remote server.

**Question**

Does this seem like a sound approach for what I want to accomplish? If so, how does one check only for deployment builds while preventing the user from tampering with the script/binary that does the checking? If not, what would make it a sound approach?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine the joy and rapture if every library you used was making calls to some random server, affecting your customers, hurting their experience. Making your development of your product a living hell for testing and distribution. Yea, that'd be a hoot.

Get a lawyer, get a solid contract, reserve the right to audit their sales, etc. Companies have had such arrangements for years, and actually abide by them with little more than a piece of paper and couple of signatures.